# Can iOS be extended Language and spell correction on iPad 3

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, internationalization

I would like to know if there is a Bosnian spelling checker for my iPad and iPhone.  I'm kind of wondering because there are more Bosnian speakers than there are Slovenian and Montenegrin combined, but currently Apple only has Slovenian listed as a language.

Comment: Is this a question or a complaint? If Apple has not included a Bosnian spell checker, you can give your feedback to Apple on http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

A search in the AppStore suggests there is no app that specializes in Bosnian spelling and grammar. Due to the nature of iOS, you can't plug in new languages unless you first jailbreak the device and then find a program that does what you ask.

As Gerry stated above in the comments, you can request this feature from Apple at http://apple.com/feedback